# Power adapter 13.5V vs 15V

Tags: voltage, ac, adapter

I'm trying to troubleshoot a problem with my Creative Inspire T6100 speakers.
They seem to be known for volume control issues.

In any case, I'm trying to determine if the power adapter is working as expected.

In the label it reads "13.5V" as output, but I am measuring about 15V.

Would it be safe to assume that the adaptor is faulty? Or should the additional output not represent a problem?

[image]

Comment: It's fine. The amplifier won't care and the voltage will probably drop when load is connected. Your question is off topic for this site as it's not a *design* question and questions about the *use* of electronic devices are off topic. 'V' for volt, not 'v'.

Comment: The adapter is likely OK. The unloaded voltage is usually measuring higher than the label says.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. and sorry if this is not the right place. I'm happy with the provided information and if the post shouldn't be here I'll be happy to delete it

Comment: @Transistor would you recommend somewhere else for the use of electronic devices? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is normal for AC transformers to be 10% higher AC with no load than rated load, in this case 5000 mA or 13.5 x 5A = 67.5VA

Due to the loss in efficiency of transformers with pulsed rectified current with poor pf and lots of ripple, this means you'd be lucky to get 10W per channel undistorted, but it is rated for only 8W probably because they went cheap on the x mF caps. ( don't believe the  T6100 MF4086 135W marketing BS for peak in 1ms )

**The 13.5V ~ suffix symbol ~, means it is AC output.** **So you are seeing a normal expected response with no load.**

If you are having lots of hum at loud levels, look at replacing the x mF cap with same or better in low ESR.  They aren't that expensive.

If it is static or intermittent on the volume control, try WD40 or replace pot.